# Подсчет затраченного времени в PHP

Tags: php

Как подсчитать время работы какой-либо процедуры. Например, я захожу в систему, делаю какие-либо действия, а когда выхожу система выдает время, которое я провел в системе в формате — `ЧЧ:ММ:СС`?

Comment: используйте функцию microtime()

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно узнать время отработки какого-то скрипта, то используйте `microtime()`, как вам подсказали в комментарии. Вызывайте функцию до отработки, сохраняйте результат, вызывайте после, сохраняйте результат - разница двух результаов и будет искомым значением. Если же вам нужно узнать время работы пользователя в каком-то разделе, сохраняйте в сессии время, когда пользователь начал работу, зафиксируйте время, когда закончил, и, опять же, разница  этих двух  значений будет результатом.

Comment: а вот с этим *зафиксируйте время, когда закончил,* трудностей не будет? Как это делать?

Comment: трудно сказать в отрыве от конкретной системы и конкретного процесса. например, взаимодействие пользователя с модулем оформления заказа - от первого товара в корзине до покупки. вообще трудностей быть не должно, если процесс взаимодействия явно подразумевает какой-либо конкретный результат: оформленный заказ, опубликованный пост и т.д.

Comment: а... от нажатия на кнопку до нажатия - это  да :)

Comment: взаимодействие оператора с системой - это, по большей части, нажатие на кнопки)

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно время в системе, т.е. время выхода - время входа, то просто записывайте в базу время входа/выхода пользователя, а потом считайте.